# AngularJS get ng-click source element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, events, this

I'm making a javascript calendar and I'd like to be able to call ng-click when I click on a day. Currently, I have that ng-click function working but I can't attach the clicked element to it:

```
var dateDiv = document.createElement('div');
dateDiv.setAttribute('ng-click', 'getTimeTables(' + fullDate + ', this);');
dateDiv.className += ' today';
$compile(dateDiv)($scope);
```

Also tried replacing this with angular's $event, and I can't get it working or I don't know how, as $($event.currentTarget).addClass('newclass'); doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Did you try this? 
Pass $event to function : 
**getTimeTables(' + fullDate + ', $event)**.
And add class like this : $(event.target).addClass();

Comment: you have a reference to the element through `dateDiv`, why do you want to get it?

Comment: @Maximus it's giving me an angular error if i do dateDiv.setAttribute('ng-click', 'getTimeTables(' + fullDateObject + ', ' + dateDiv + ');');

Comment: @Xabi, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40318484/2545680) for the way you want it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the element through `$event.target`

```
var dateDiv = document.createElement('div');
dateDiv.setAttribute('ng-click', 'getTimeTables(' + fullDate + ', $event);');
dateDiv.className += ' today';
$compile(dateDiv)($scope);
```

And inside `getTimeTables`:

```
$scope.getTimeTables = function(fullDate, $event) {
  $($event.target).addClass('newclass');
}
```

Comment: you're welcome) however, you may reconsider your approach and use reference to the element inside a directive without passing it through callback